# visualize my website result using elastic stack

Tags: security, visualization, kibana, elastic-stack, scanning

I have a website to scan the URL and show the result to the users, but I want to visualize this result using kibana, is there any possibility to do that?

I search about this since five days, so if there is no answer, at least give me reference or any thing about the elastic stack specialists